# Javascript/jQuery - input with some pre-filled characters on some positions, and other empty ready-to-fill positions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have an input of type text, having preset on position 3 and 6 a pre-defined character, like '$' for example, and then allowing to fill positions 1,2,4,5,7,8,9 and 10 with any other character?

So for example, when the user opens the page and first sees this input, the stuff displayed in the input
would be: 
`_ _ $ _ _ $ _ _ _ _` 
and he can only fill those positions marked with "_".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the code you're working with?  Have you tried an input mask?

Comment: I don't think code I am working with would be necessary in here. What I have tried is adding a pattern constraint on the input field + adding after the 2nd and 5th character my special symbols (like '$') automatically, but this isn't exactly what I waned. However, your suggestion with the input mask is very useful and I will try to use those (I did not previously know about them). Thanks!

Comment: I assure you, adding your code is necessary.  We'll help you fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I know what you mean and I totally agree with you, code and previous tries are always good to mention, but in this case, my previous code was based on an idea which was not what I actually wanted. I admit I should have stated what I have already tried, but regarding the code I wrote, I still believe it is not necessary. And I also didn't ask for code to be written for me, I just asked if is possible to have something like this and how could I achieve it, and your reply was just was I was looking for. Thanks again, and if you post your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it.